# It is possible to isolate for the angle $a_B$ in the following equation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Is it possible to isolate for $a_B$ in the following equation ?

$$\displaystyle{A}={\left\lbrace{{sin}^{{-{1}}}{\left[\frac{{{W}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}}}{{{\left\lbrace\frac{{{\left(\frac{{{\left\lbrace{W}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}\right\rbrace}\cdot{\left\lbrace{W}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}\right\rbrace}}}{{{\left[{H}-{\left({L}\cdot sin{{\left({90}-{a}{B}\right)}}\right)}\right]}\cdot{4}}}\right)}+{\left[{H}-{\left({L}\cdot sin{{\left({90}-{a}{B}\right)}}\right)}\right]}}}{{2}}\right\rbrace}⋅{2}}}\right]}}⋅{2}\right\rbrace}⋅{\left\lbrace\frac{{{\left(\frac{{{\left\lbrace{W}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}\right\rbrace}\cdot{\left\lbrace{W}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}+{\left[{L}\cdot sin{{\left({a}{B}\right)}}\right]}\right\rbrace}}}{{{\left[{H}-{\left({L}\cdot Sin{{\left({90}-{a}{B}\right)}}\right)}\right]}\cdot{4}}}\right)}+{\left[{H}-{\left({L}\cdot sin{{\left({90}-{a}{B}\right)}}\right)}\right]}}}{{2}}\right\rbrace}$$

I think I fixed the issue, but it makes the equation a little more difficult.

I know A, W, L and H, can I somehow isolate and sovle for $aB$ ?

Comment: This seems to simplify to $A=\sin^{-1}(W+2L\sin(a_B))$. Is there a mistake somewhere in your formula?

Comment: My first equation was:

$$A = \sin^{-1}{\!\left(\frac{W + L\sin{\!(a)} + L\sin{\!(a)}}{\left(\frac{(W + L\sin{\!(a)} + L\sin{\!(a)})(W + L\sin{\!(a)} + L\sin{\!(a)})}{4(H - L\sin{\!(90^{\circ}-a)})} + H - L\sin{\!(90^{\circ}-a)}\right) / 2 \cdot 2}\right)} \cdot 2\left(\frac{(W + L\sin{\!(a)} + L\sin{\!(a)})(W + L\sin{\!(a)} + L\sin{\!(a)})}{4(H - L\sin{\!(90^{\circ}-a)})} + (H - L\sin{\!(90^{\circ}-a)})\right) / 2$$

But an online math program simplified it to the one shown in the OP.

A mod also changed the formatting, so hopefully they didn't accidently change the content.

Comment: Now that I look at it, even the above isn't fully correct, because the final bit should also be enclosed in brackets (everything after the *2 to the end.  I will try to write it from scratch again to see if it can be cleaner

Comment: I fixed the OP, I think.

Comment: You can simplify further. But at the end you will end up with an expression $$A=x\sin^{-1}(2x)$$
I am not sure if this has a nice inverse, but that's the direction you should pursue.

Comment: A = (Asin(CL / (R * 2)) * 2) * R ---

This is the basic form of the equation.  Is there a way to isolate CL in this simple version?  I don't know how (if it is even possible) to isolate a variable that is used in the middle of an equation like this.

Comment: I think you have some errors in this last form. But you can leave just the sine function on one side, then take the $\sin^{-1}$ from both sides

Comment: Thank you Andrei, with that note in mind I was able to convert it to -- Sin(A/2/R) * R * 2 = CL -- Note that the Sin function is working in radians for this equation, not degrees.  I think this is a step forward, but then it complicates things again because R = {(((CL*CL) / (HA*4)) + HA) / 2} .  Once I make that substitution, I end up with a CL on both sides again, so I am going to have to try to work it some more to get it back to a single CL on the one side again.